# KShell script skips commands when scheduled in cron

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have a Kshell script which executes a java program.

```
/path/to/java -jar jarfile.jar some parameters > log
Same line 5 times with different parameters appending output to log file.
cat log | mail -s email@email.com
```

The problem I keep having is when I put this script in cron only the last line which takes the log files & sends email is executed. All the above actual functionally required lines are ignored. I get a blank email on cron scheduled time, but the script should take around 1 hour.

But when I run the script manually, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is "Kshell" the Korn Shell?  Put a `2>&1`   after `> log` to get the error messages mailed to you, too.  They might tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, its Korn shell. The java code is not even executing. There is no entry in log.

Comment: When you redirect error output (the `2>&1`) you should get at least some error message, e.g. `/path/to/java: not found`.   Could you use a full path for the log file, e.g. `/tmp/log` ?

Comment: I added 2>&1 as you said. There is no entry in log. Yes, I am using a full path for log file. One thing I noticed in cron mail is that "unable to access jarfile.jar"  and "cat: 0652-050 Cannot open /path/to/log".  BTW the log and jarfile.jar has full permissions

Comment: Are you sure, the script is executed under ksh? Did you verify, that you have no dependencies from the environment? Scripts on cron have a very different (reduced) environment. I suggest you trace the execution of the script (I think in ksh this is also `set -x`) and analyze the output.

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. I have resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I checked the cron mails for problem. For "unable to access jarfile.jar" I added complete path in the script and for "cat: 0652-050 Cannot open /path/to/log", I created the log file before hand using touch command. Now my script looks like this.

```
touch /path/to/log
/path/to/java -jar /path/to/jarfile.jar some parameters > /path/to/log
Same line 5 times with different parameters appending output to log file.
cat /path/to/log | mail -s email@email.com
```

I came to know giving absolute path is the key to avoid these kinds of problems.